# Getting range of data property using OWL API

Tags: owl-api

I am using OWL API to get the range of a data property as follows:

```
OWLDataProperty dataProperty = ontologyManager.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLDataProperty("http://schema.mobivoc.org/powerInKW");
Set<OWLDataPropertyRangeAxiom> ranges = ontology.getOWLOntology().getDataPropertyRangeAxioms(dataProperty);
        for (OWLDataPropertyRangeAxiom range : ranges) {
            String rangeString = range.getRange().getDataRangeType().getIRI().getIRIString();

        }
```

The property `"http://schema.mobivoc.org/powerInKW"` has the range `xsd:Double`. But the above code is returning `owl:DataType`. While I agree that `xsd:Double` is an instance of `owl:DataType`, how to get the actual range, in this case `owl:DataType` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `getDataRangeType()` in your code, which moves you from the range to its type. But what you want is the range, so skip that method and just use the range. You can create a visitor to navigate the different ranges, or you can cast to OWLDatatype for plain datatypes.